# Clojure: rest vs. next

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between `rest` and `next` in Clojure. [The official site's page on laziness](http://clojure.org/lazy) indicates that the preference should probably be to use `rest`, but it doesn't really explain clearly the difference between the two. Can anybody provide some insight?

Comment: This point isn't worth a separate answer: What the answers so far have not made fully explicit is that `()` is true, while `nil` is false.  So `(defn keep-going [my-coll] (if (rest my-coll) (keep-going (rest my-coll)) "Finished.")` will keep going forever--or rather, will overflow the stack--while `(defn keep-going [my-coll] (if (next my-coll) (keep-going (next my-coll)) "Finished.")` will finish.  (OP surely has figure this out by now; I'm adding this remark for others.)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

As the page you linked described, `next` is stricter than (the new behaviour of) `rest` because it needs to evaluate the structure of the lazy cons to know whether to return `nil` or a seq.

`rest` on the other hand always returns a seq, so nothing needs to be evaluated until you actually use the result of `rest`. In other words, `rest` is more lazy than `next`.

Comment: OK, I think I might understand what you mean. Are you saying that `next` always returns a cons cell, whereas `rest` merely returns an ISeq (or whatever type it actually is)?

Comment: @Daniel: `next` returns `nil` or a non-empty `seq`. `rest` always returns a `seq`, which might be empty.

Comment: So I take it that, for some sequences, determining whether there are more elements is an expensive operation. With a normal list of cons cells, I would think that it's trivial to determine whether you have reached the end of the list. However, with a lazy sequence (from lazy-seq, perhaps), this determination might be expensive. 

I didn't quite understand that nil was different from the empty sequence. It sounds like subsequences produces with rest make weaker guarantees and, therefore, can be more efficient.

Comment: To add to the confusion: `(drop 1 s)` is lazier than `rest` because it don't force partial realization of s. `rest` is not guaranteed to only realize the 1st item of the lazy seq. It depends on the lazy seq.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Using Clojure 1.10.1 [this code](https://gist.github.com/sepp2k/a4dd31ec1d70f76bed1c3364aac46fb9) will print "make-empty was called", but [this code](https://gist.github.com/sepp2k/e74da85cca02b37daa6a364e8a15f9e6) will not. So it looks to me like the difference is still there.

Comment: @sepp2k Thanks for this, answer has been changed.

Answer (score 35):

It's easy if you have this:

```
(next '(1))
=> nil
```

So `next` looks at the next thing and if the line is empty it returns `nil` instead of an empty seq. This means that it needs to look ahead (to the first item it would return) which makes it not fully lazy (maybe you don't need the next value, but `next` wastes the compute time to look ahead).

```
(rest '(1))
=> ()
```

`rest` doesn't look ahead and just returns the rest of the seq.

Maybe you think, Why even bother using two different things here? The reason is that you normally want to know if there is nothing left in the seq and just return `nil`, but in some cases where performance is very important and evaluating one more item could mean tremendous effort you can use `rest`.

Comment: just to beat it to death:
(rest nil) => ()

Answer (score 22):

`next` is like `(seq (rest ...))`.

`rest` will return the remaining piece of a sequence. If that piece of the sequence has not yet been realized, `rest` doesn't force it. It won't even tell you if there are more elements left in the sequence.

`next` does the same thing but then forces at least one element of the sequence to be realized. So if `next` returns `nil`, you know there aren't any more elements left in the sequence.

Answer (score 4):

I now prefer to use `next` with recursion, as the escape-evaluation is simpler/cleaner:

```
(loop [lst a-list]
    (when lst
        (recur (next lst))
```

vs

```
(loop [lst a-list]
    (when-not (empty? lst)   ;; or (when (seq? lst)
        (recur (rest lst))
```

A case for using `rest`, though, would be if you use a collection as a queue or stack.  In that case you want your function to return an empty collection when popping or dequeueing the last item.

Comment: The first example does a useless recursive call if `lst` is empty because the empty list is truthy. A nice way to test for "non-nilness": `(when (some? lst) ...` (via https://tonsky.me/blog/readable-clojure/ )

Comment: I typically use `if-let`, as in:

    `(loop [lst lst]
      (if-let [[elem & lst] (seq lst)]
        (recur lst)))`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little table useful when writing code that traverses a sequence using "mundane" recursion (using the stack) or using `recur` (using tail-recursive optimization, thus actually looping).

[image: rest, next, first, seq, oh my!]

Note the differences in behaviour of `rest` and `next`. Combined with `seq` this leads to the following idiom, where end-of-list is tested via `seq` and rest-of-list is obtained via `rest` (adapted from "The Joy of Clojure"):

```
; "when (seq s)":
; case s nonempty -> truthy -> go
; case s empty    -> nil -> falsy -> skip
; case s nil      -> nil -> falsy -> skip

(defn print-seq [s]
  (when (seq s)          
     (assert (and (not (nil? s)) (empty? s)))
     (prn (first s))     ; would give nil on empty seq
     (recur (rest s))))  ; would give an empty sequence on empty seq
```

**Why is `next` more eager than `rest`?**

If `(next coll)` is evaluated, the result can be `nil`. This must be known immediately (i.e. `nil` must actually be returned) because the caller may branch on based on the truthyness of `nil`.

If `(rest coll)` is evaluated, the result cannot be `nil`. Unless the caller then tests the result for empty-ness using a function call, generation of a "next element" in a lazy-seq can be delayed to the time it is actually needed.

**Example**

A completely lazy collection, all the computations are "on hold until needed"

```
(def x
   (lazy-seq
      (println "first lazy-seq evaluated")
      (cons 1
         (lazy-seq
            (println "second lazy-seq evaluated")
            (cons 2
               (lazy-seq
                  (println "third lazy-seq evaluated")))))))           

;=> #'user/x
```

The computation of "x" is now suspended at the first "lazy-seq".

Using the eager next after that, we see two evaluations:

```
(def y (next x))

;=> first lazy-seq evaluated
;=> second lazy-seq evaluated
;=> #'user/y

(type y)

;=> clojure.lang.Cons

(first y)

;=> 2
```

- The first lazy-seq is evaluated, leading to the printout `first lazy-seq evaluated`
- This results in a nonempty structure: a cons with 1 on the left and a lazy-seq on the right.
- `next` may have to return `nil` if the right branch is empty. So we need to check one level deeper.
- The second lazy-seq is evaluated, leading to the printout `second lazy-seq evaluated`
- This results in a nonempty structure: a cons with 2 on the left and a lazy-seq on the right.
- So don't return `nil`, return the cons instead.
- When obtaining the `first` of `y`, there is nothing do do except retrieve 2 from the already-obtained cons.

Using the lazier `rest`, we see one evaluation (note that you have to redefine `x` first to make the this work)

```
(def y (rest x))

;=> first lazy-seq evaluated
;=> #'user/y

(type y)

;=> clojure.lang.LazySeq

(first y)

;=> second lazy-seq evaluated
;=> 2
```

- The first lazy-seq is evaluated, leading to the printout `first lazy-seq evaluated`
- This results in a nonempty structure: a cons with 1 on the left and a lazy-seq on the right.
- `rest` never returns `nil`, even if the lazy-seq on the right would evaluate to the empty seq.
- If the caller needs to know more (is the seq empty?), he can perform the appropriate test later on the lazy-seq.
- So we are done, just return the lazy-seq as result.
- When obtaining the `first` of `y`, the lazy-seq needs to be evaluated one step further to obtain the 2

**Sidebar**

Note that `y`'s type is `LazySeq`. This may seem obvious, but `LazySeq` is not at "thing of the language", it is a "thing of the runtime", representing not a result but a state of computation. In fact `(type y)` being `clojure.lang.LazySeq` just means "we don't know the type yet, you have to do more to find out". Whenever a Clojure function like `nil?` hits something that has type `clojure.lang.LazySeq`, computation will occur!

**P.S.**

In Joy of Clojure, 2nd edition, on page 126, there is an example using `iterate` to illustrate the difference between `next` and `rest`.

```
(doc iterate)
;=> Returns a lazy sequence of x, (f x), (f (f x)) etc. f must be free
;   of side-effects
```

As it turns out, the example doesn't work. In this case, there actually is no difference in the behaviour between `next` and `rest`. Not sure why, maybe `next` knows it won't ever return `nil` here and just defaults to the behaviour of `rest`.

```
(defn print-then-inc [x] (do (print "[" x "]") (inc x)))

(def very-lazy (iterate print-then-inc 1))

(def very-lazy (rest(rest(rest(iterate print-then-inc 1)))))
;=> [ 1 ][ 2 ]#'user/very-lazy
(first very-lazy)
;=> [ 3 ]4

(def less-lazy (next(next(next(iterate print-then-inc 1)))))
;=> [ 1 ][ 2 ]#'user/less-lazy
(first less-lazy)
;=> [ 3 ]4
```

Comment: Fixed the "lazyness" part because sepp2k told me I'm totally wrong.

Comment: RE the Joy of Clojure example: Starting with Clojure 1.7, `iterate` is longer implemented with `lazy-seq` and so can have special handling of `next`. Since `iterate` never terminates, there's no need for its `next` to realize the next step to satisfy the requirement of returning `nil` at the next of the sequence.