# Realization timing of lazy sequence

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

```
(defn square [x]
  (do
    (println (str "Processing: " x))
    (* x x)))

(println (map square '(1 2 3 4 5)))
```

Why is the output

```
(Processing: 1 
Processing: 2 
1 Processing: 3 
4 Processing: 4 
9 Processing: 5 
16 25)
```

not

```
(Processing: 1
1 Processing: 2
4 Processing: 3 
9 Processing: 4 
16 Processing: 5 
25)
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`println` uses `[[x & xs] xs]` destructuring form in its [implementation](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/92b4fc76e59e68d3bdae4ebd5b8deec915cb7ab5/src/clj/clojure/core_print.clj#L40-L62). This is equivelent to `[x (first xs), xs (next xs)]` and [`next` is less lazy than `rest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288476/clojure-rest-vs-next), so it realizes the two items before printing the first.

For example,

```
=> (defn fn1 [[x & xs]] nil)
#'user/fn1
=> (fn1 (map square '(1 2 3 4 5)))
Processing: 1
Processing: 2
nil
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `map` is lazy. It uses `lazy-seq` under the covers, which [pre-caches the result of `rest`](http://clojure.org/lazy). So you see the two `println` statements appear when your code grabs the first value of the `map` sequence.

See also this blog post: [Lazy Sequences](http://www.maybetechnology.com/2011/07/lazy-sequences.html)

Comment: lazy-seq does not pre-cache the result of `rest`. The article you linked to is a many-years-old description of some work in progress that never got applied, attempting to solve a problem that no longer exists. alice's explanation is correct. *edit* okay that work did get applied, but I don't see how you got the impression there's any pre-caching going on - if there were, lazy seqs would not be lazy at all, because they would recursively "pre-cache" the whole lazy sequence!

Comment: Ok, so I mis-used the term "pre-cache" further misled by that blog post. What I meant was "evaluates the first two elements before printing either of them."

Answer (score 1):

Are you like me to learn with code snippets? Here are some.

Let's have a look at the documentation of `map`.

```
user=> (doc map)
-------------------------
clojure.core/map
([f coll] [f c1 c2] [f c1 c2 c3] [f c1 c2 c3 & colls])
  Returns a lazy sequence consisting of the result of applying f to the
  set of first items of each coll, followed by applying f to the set
  of second items in each coll, until any one of the colls is
  exhausted.  Any remaining items in other colls are ignored. Function
  f should accept number-of-colls arguments.
nil
```

`map` returns a lazy sequence (you should already read the references given by @noahz). To fully realize the lazy sequence (it's often not a good practice as the lazy seq might be infinite and hence never end) you can use `dorun` or `doall`.

```
user=> (doc dorun)
-------------------------
clojure.core/dorun
([coll] [n coll])
  When lazy sequences are produced via functions that have side
  effects, any effects other than those needed to produce the first
  element in the seq do not occur until the seq is consumed. dorun can
  be used to force any effects. Walks through the successive nexts of
  the seq, does not retain the head and returns nil.
nil
user=> (doc doall)
-------------------------
clojure.core/doall
([coll] [n coll])
  When lazy sequences are produced via functions that have side
  effects, any effects other than those needed to produce the first
  element in the seq do not occur until the seq is consumed. doall can
  be used to force any effects. Walks through the successive nexts of
  the seq, retains the head and returns it, thus causing the entire
  seq to reside in memory at one time.
nil
```

Although they seem similar they are not - mind the difference with how they treat the head of the realized sequence.

With the knowledge, you can influence the way the map lazy sequence behaves with `doall`.

```
user=> (defn square [x]
  #_=>   (println (str "Processing: " x))
  #_=>   (* x x))
#'user/square
user=> (doall (map square '(1 2 3 4 5)))
Processing: 1
Processing: 2
Processing: 3
Processing: 4
Processing: 5
(1 4 9 16 25)
```

As you might've noticed I also changed the definition of the `square` function as you don't need `do` inside the function (it's implicit with the `defn` macro).

In the [Clojure Programming](http://www.clojurebook.com/) book, there's the sentence you may like for the case of `'(1 2 3 4 5)`:

> "Most people simply use a vector literal for such cases, within which member expressions
>   will always be evaluated."

Instead of copying the relevant sections to support this statement, I'd rather recommend the book as it's worth the time and money.